# web2py : SQLFORM.grid paginate parameter

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

I have a form defined as below.

```
grid3 = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, headers=headers, fields=fields,
                     create=False, user_signature=True, deletable=True,
                     maxtextlength=100, editable=False, paginate=1000)
```

But i can see only 100 rows per page and then it roll overs to next page. Is 100 the max row per page.

Setting a value less than 100 works but a value more than 100 limits it to 100 rows.

Comment: This should not be the case and I cannot reproduce it. I suggest you post on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&pli=1#!forum/web2py) and attach a minimal app that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am sorry. Tested it now. I had lot of SQLFORM.grid and I was making edit to wrong Form and expecting the result in a different View. Apologizing for my mistake.